# jquery: how to prevent dropdown change after user made selection?

Tags: jquery, html-select

Hej Folks!

I got following script-example to make some selections:

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/dataminer/7zYUS/1/

```
$(function(){

var My_2_MadeSelection = {

// Second Selection
'001': ['004'],
'002': ['005'],
'003': ['006']
};

// Third Selection
var My_3_MadeSelection = {

'001': ['007'],
'002': ['008'],
'003': ['009']
};

// Fourth Selection
var My_4_MadeSelection = {

'001': ['010'],
'002': ['011'],
'003': ['012']
};


// var
$('#001').change(function() {
var availableMy_2_MadeSelection = My_2_MadeSelection[this.options[this.selectedIndex].value];
var availableMy_3_MadeSelection = My_3_MadeSelection[this.options[this.selectedIndex].value];
var availableMy_4_MadeSelection = My_4_MadeSelection[this.options[this.selectedIndex].value];

// groups
$('#002 option').attr('disabled', function () { return $.inArray(this.value, availableMy_2_MadeSelection) == -1 });
$('#003 option').attr('disabled', function () { return $.inArray(this.value, availableMy_3_MadeSelection) == -1 });
$('#004 option').attr('disabled', function () { return $.inArray(this.value, availableMy_4_MadeSelection) == -1 });
});

// change
$('#001').change(function() {
if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value === 1) {
$('#002,#003,#004').attr("disabled", "disabled");
} else {
$('#002,#003,#004').removeAttr("disabled");
}
});

// trigger
$('#001').trigger('change');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="selectdiv">
<p>1. Select</p>
<select id="001" class="001" name="001">
    <option selected="selected" value="001">001a</option>
    <option value="002">001b</option>
    <option value="003">001c</option>
  </select>

<p>2. Select</p>
<select id="002" class="002" name="002">
    <option selected="selected" value="004">002a</option>
    <option value="005">002b</option>
    <option value="006">002c</option>
  </select>


<p>3. Select</p>
<select id="003" class="003" name="003">
    <option selected="selected" value="007">003a</option>
    <option value="008">003b</option>
    <option value="009">003c</option>
  </select>


<p>4. Select</p>
<select id="004" class="004" name="004">
    <option selected="selected" value="010">004a</option>
    <option value="011">004b</option>
    <option value="012">004c</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Problem: If a user now made all his/her selections the user is able to change first again, what leads to a "not-available cmbination". :(

1.) Is there a solution to disable the first dropdown, after a user changed second / third / fourth dropdown?

2.) Or is it possible to check values an give an alert like "if you change this, you'll have to change other again?"

3.) Or reset 2nd/3rd/4th values to "default" again if first dropdown was changed again?

Sory for my bad english. Hope someone understand my problem. 
Thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer to 1st question,

To disable, you will have to keep flags. You may keep check which all selects have been changed.

Example,

```
var changed1 = false,
    changed2 = false,
    changed3 = false,
    changed4 = false;
```

Then on changing any, say 1st,

```
 $("#001").change(function(){
         changed1 = true;
         if(changed2 && changed3 && changed4){
                $("#001").prop('disabled', true);
         }
  });

 $("#002").change(function(){
         changed2 = true;

}); 
$("#003").change(function(){
         changed3 = true;
}); 
$("#004").change(function(){
         changed1 = true;
});
```

Thus you can keep the log of which all inputs have been changed.

## Answer to 2nd,

I don't understand why are you even asking this,

```
$('#001').change(function(){
    alert("If you change this, you also will have to change the other 3.");
});
```

## Answer to 3rd,

This would reset 2nd, 3rd, 4th on changing the first.

```
$('#001').change(function(){
    $('#002, #003, #004').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

And you may even change the 'selectedIndex' according to your need.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7zYUS/2/)** for 3rd.

Comment: Had to change .prop to .attr cause firebug didnt like it.... Thank you so much! 1st and 3rd works fine. 2nd is a bit annoying. Maybe its possible to alert only if 001 has changed after 002, 003 and 004 changed?

Comment: @Dataminer That would be same as the 1st. Just instead of disabling the #001 there, you put the alert there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different format. You can figure the others out using Optimus Prime's answer.

Eg. Disable the first drop-down. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zYUS/3/)

```
$(function(){

    var My_2_MadeSelection = {
        // Second Selection
        '001': ['004'],
        '002': ['005'],
        '003': ['006']
    };

    // Third Selection
    var My_3_MadeSelection = {
        '001': ['007'],
        '002': ['008'],
        '003': ['009']
    };

    // Fourth Selection
    var My_4_MadeSelection = {
        '001': ['010'],
        '002': ['011'],
        '003': ['012']
    };

    $('select').change(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == '001') {
            // var
            var availableMy_2_MadeSelection = My_2_MadeSelection[this.options[this.selectedIndex].value];
            var availableMy_3_MadeSelection = My_3_MadeSelection[this.options[this.selectedIndex].value];
            var availableMy_4_MadeSelection = My_4_MadeSelection[this.options[this.selectedIndex].value];
            // groups
            $('#002 option').attr('disabled', function () { return $.inArray(this.value, availableMy_2_MadeSelection) == -1 });
            $('#003 option').attr('disabled', function () { return $.inArray(this.value, availableMy_3_MadeSelection) == -1 });
            $('#004 option').attr('disabled', function () { return $.inArray(this.value, availableMy_4_MadeSelection) == -1 });
        }else{
            $('#001').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

    // trigger
    $('#001').trigger('change');
});
```